# where to see the response.write() messages

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

I am using the follwing http request in my Angular JS code

```
$http.get('http://my url/.../')
       .success(function(data, status, headers, config){
          console.log('response',data);
       })
       .error(function() {
          console.log('Error');
        });
```

and in my node JS, I am using

```
response.write(data);
```

where can I get that data value. Because I am not getting the any console with the data.
If I use

```
response.send(data);
```

then I am getting the console log from the my JS file with the data

Comment: Need to show more node code...snippets shown are worthless without context. Inspect the actual request in browser dev tools network tab for more clues

Comment: sorry, msg means the response object

Comment: I am doing the same thing which 'ikacir' mentioned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data is being sent in both cases. Only the `send` method closes the connection.

The issues is that the `success` callback only runs when the request *completes*. The `write` method sends data to the client, but it does not complete the request. The client is still waiting for the server to say, "*Okay, that's the whole message; there's no more to send.*" Until the server does that, the `success` callback won't run.

The `send` method (and the `end` method) close the connection. When the connection closes, the `success` method runs.

it appears that you want to send a *continuous stream of data* (since you don't want to end the connection), in which case, you could [log XHR `progress` events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest#Monitoring_progress). Unfortunately, [the `$http` interface does not currently expose `progress` events](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1934).

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are using Express with Node. With `response.write`, you are just writing the response without sending it. You then have to call `response.end` to say: "this response is ready, send it." `response.send` writes and sends the response.

```
response.send(data);
```

is the same as:

```
response.write(data);
response.end();
```

Comment: yes, but what I am asking is, If I use the send then I am getting the data, but not with the write. Is write will sends the data where send will sends

Answer (score 0):

It should simply be:

```
response.end(data);
```

You have to end it to flush the response.